# NHibernate transactions within UnitOfWork Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, transactions, unit-of-work

The project I am working on has a UnitOfWork defined for an entire session (as seems to be standard practice with MVC + NHibernate sites)

WHat I need to do though, is be able to loop over a collection of items and prcess them one by one in their own "local" transaction.

something like this:

```
foreach(var item in CollectionOfItems)
 {
      using (ITransaction transaction = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction())
      {
         //do work on item. rollback on failure, 
         //but it should not affect the other items
      }
 }
```

But this won't work because the BeginTransaction line is using the same "outer" session.
How can I get a self-contained "local" session to perform a transaction on a small block of code? I think the session is being injected into the unit of work in the following code. I don't know exactly how, though:

The UnitOfWOrk class has the following constructor

```
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        CurrentSession = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        _transaction = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction();
    }
```

It is registered via:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle())
            .Use<UnitOfWork>();
```

So whenever a controller returns a response, the session gets flushed. This is where I am confused.  I don't always want everything to be all or nothing.

EDIT:

Here is all the code for the NHibernate Registration process

```
    public NHibernateRegistry()
    {
        FluentConfiguration fluentConfig = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ShowSql().ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("conn")))
            .ProxyFactoryFactory(typeof (ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMap>());


        Configuration configuration = fluentConfig.BuildConfiguration();

        ConfigureNhibernateValidator(configuration);

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = fluentConfig.BuildSessionFactory();

        For<Configuration>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Singleton().Use(configuration);

        For<ISessionFactory>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Singleton().Use(sessionFactory);

        For<ISession>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle())
            .Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());

        For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle())
            .Use<UnitOfWork>();

        For<ITssPrincipal>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(container => BuildUserInstanceFromThreadCurrentPrincipal());

        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.TheCallingAssembly();
            x.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
```

EDIT: DI problem example
In the below example, you see tha RepoA  is DI'd with RepoB and both get a UnitOfWork supplied by StructureMap.

```
public RepoA(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ITssPrincipal principal,
     IRepoB repoB)
{
}

public RepoB(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ITssPrincipal principal)
{
}
```

Even if I create a new session in a function in RepoA, repoB will still be using the original UnitOfWork Session

Comment: Is your session factory available within the class you doing the foreach loop? Instead of using UnitOfWork.CurrentSession are you instead able to create a new session within the loop using the factory, and then call BeginTransaction() against that session?

Comment: I've added more code that displays how the main session gets set up. Is there a way to use fluentConfig.BuildSessionFactory() in my loop somehow?

Comment: Randy's response looks right, but to add to your last comment: always remember that sessions are cheap, but session *factories* are expensive. So always avoid creating new factories (and by using dependency injection you never really have to).

Comment: I think DI is my biggest problem right now. Since StructureMap is injectiogn all my repo classes with a UnitOfWork session, I have no way of making them use the newly created session (since they were already instantiated by this point)

Comment: I've updated my OP with an example

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your MVC website is using StructureMap as it's dependency injection container which makes it very easy to do what you want.

You have a couple of options but the easiest would be to just request a new instance of ISession from StructureMap. That will return you a new and different ISession than the one being used by the UnitOfWork.

Here's an example:

```
var session = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>();

using ( var tx = session.BeginTransaction() )
{
    try
    {
        // Do your work here

        tx.Commit();
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        tx.Rollback();

        throw;
    }
}
```

Because you are using a DI container, you could also leverage StructureMap's dependency injection and have a new ISession injected into the constructor of your controller/class/repository, etc. that way you don't have to call StructureMap's ObjectFactory.GetInstance<>() method.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is getting me close to what I need, but I still have a problem, the repository functions that are being called still have a reference to the original UnitOfWork session. Is there a way to make any repo call within the above context use the newly instantiated session?

Comment: @getit If you have further dependencies that need this newly created NHibernate session, then it sounds like what you want is a new UnitOfWork per item in your collection. At that point, the architecture of your application really comes into play as to whether that is possible or not. Some UnitOfWork implementations can support nested UnitOfWorks. If your application cannot support nested UnitOfWorks, then you'll need to get creative. One option could be to close/commit the initial UnitOfWork and manually start and commit a new UnitOfWork per item in your collection.